# How to update component value from parent using react

Tags: reactjs

I am new in REACT I am try to make hello world.

My component TABLE contains components ROW.

I can pass some data from TABLE to ROW using props.

I have button in TABLE and I want on click event change data in component ROW. 
How can I do this? All ROW in table has unicate props ID. Can you make some simple demo for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a function inside the `TABLE` component that you want to run when a `ROW` is clicked, you can pass that function as a property to the `ROW` container, and use `this.props.onClick` to call the function from the parent container when something happened inside the child component:

Table:

```
onRowClick() {
    alert('Row Clicked')
}

render() {
    return <Row onClick={this.onRowClick} />
}
```

Row:

```
render() {
    return <tr onClick={this.props.onClick} />
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. What about some counter which will be iterated over each click? Can you give me example for two rows?

Comment: It is only example.

Comment: You can use the state to count the total number of times the function was called...

Comment: What about when I have X row?

Comment: each click will call the function, and you do this increment inside that function. it doesn't really matter how many rows you have.

Comment: It is mean that number of rows = number of variables in state?  When each row has own counter...

Comment: you want to know for each row how many times it was clicked? or all-over the rows?

Comment: Lol, I have two rows in same table. Each row has own counter. I want increment both on on click on some button. First by +1 and second +5 - for example.

Comment: If the row need it's own counter - you should increment that counter of that row...